# Maya - Automatically run function on an uncaught exception

Tags: python, exception, maya

I am trying to build a function that runs only when uncaught exceptions are raised.

A solution that I found online is to override / wrap `sys.excepthook`, like this:

```
import sys


def exception(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Uncaught exception was found', args, kwargs)


sys.excepthook = exception


def foo():
    bar()


def bar():
    raise ValueError('I am an exception. Catch me if you can!')


foo()
```

If you save the above code into a file and run it using `python`, it will print "Uncaught exception was found". And if you add a try/except around `bar()`, it doesn't run. This is exactly the functionality that I want.

This even works in an interactive Python shell and using `mayapy`. The only situation that I've found it does not work is within Autodesk Maya itself. You can run the above code in the Script Editor, as a menu item, or as a shelf button and it does not run the contents of the `exception` function. Oddly enough, it does work in Nuke however (both using its python interpreter and from inside of Nuke).

So to summarize - the above method works by:

- Saving the text as a file and executing it with `python`
- Running `python` as an interactive shell, pasting the code and running it in there
- Saving the text as a file and executing it with `mayapy`
- Running `mayapy` as an interactive shell, pasting the code and running it in there

And doesn't work by:

- Running the code in the Maya Script Editor or as a shelf button or menu item.

If there's another, better method to achieve what I want then please let me know. Otherwise, is there a reason why this technique isn't working? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Didn't my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, your response was perfect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it would be cleaner to let meddling with excepthook to interactive shells and instead wrapping your `main` in a `try/except` and then just reraise the exception after your special treatment like so:

```
def main():
    foo()

try:
    main()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Uncaught exception was found:   {type(e).__name__}: {e}')
    raise
```

But if you like to go with excepthook, [this blog](http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2013/03/my-entry.html) describes a solution for maya:

```
import maya.utils

def myExceptCB(etype, value, tb, detail=2):

    # do something here...

    print "do something here..."

    return maya.utils._formatGuiException(etype, value, tb, detail)

maya.utils.formatGuiException = myExceptCB
```